# How do I export the Browsing History in Firefox?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, data-recovery, history

I lost a load of open tabs in Firefox that I want to recover. The details are in the browsing history but it is not the most friendly area of Firefox to wade through. The Export option there actually exports bookmarks. I want to export my browsing history as a text file so I can search, dedup, etc in a text editor. I can not work out a way of exporting the browsing history so any suggestions much appreciated.

Firefox 3.5.5
Windows XP Pro

Comment: As for me, this addon
https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/ works. But this SQLite Browser, recommended by John T was unable to open my 20 Mb file

Comment: http://sessionmanager.mozdev.org/ it saves the opened tabs, so you can restore them after a crash, even if firefox would lose them.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Browsing history is stored in a file called **places.sqlite** in your profile folder. On Windows it is located in the randomly named `.default` folder found in this directory:

```
%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
```

This file format is not easily edited in a text file, but you can use [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) (free and open source) to view the file.

Comment: That's a start at least (an impressive one, at that.)  I had to play around to see for myself.  It looks like `select * from moz_places order by id desc;` would give you an in-app list of your recorded browsing history sorted from newest to oldest.  But, if you want to extract the data for manipulation you'll have to do `File | Export | Table as CSV File` and then open it in OpenOffice Calc or Excel and twiddle from there.

Comment: +1 JMD and thanks for extra help. I was not 100% sure on what do do with the DB!!

Comment: if you want the corresponding icons, they're now in **favicons.sqlite**. this is how I got the corresponding icons of places.sqlite>moz_places>url  : look at this line https://github.com/FuPeiJiang/firefoxSqliteHistoryToHTML/blob/c222940bd2d216c5a58044cfd83cbfca4bbf4102/index.js#L27

Answer (score 10):

For modern era (it's March 2014 as I write this) Firefox users on Windows machines, you can give Nirsoft's Firefox History Viewer a try:
    http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/mozilla_history_view.html

Not sure if it can read the (very old and outdated) history.dat format, but it can filter, slice, dice, chop, puree, scramble, and otherwise do all kinds of fancy things (but it cannot make your coffee and serve it to you, sorry!) with the history data in the "places.sqlite" format, and then export it to several common formats ranging from text to html to csv to xml to whatever.

Comment: It's Jan 2018, almost 4 years later, and this software still works correctly even on the latest Firefox Quantum. I was able to successfully export my browser history of nearly 1300 items into `.txt` and `.csv` format. Good day! :D

Answer (score 4):

Use the [History Export](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/history-export/) add-on which can export to .html, .txt and .json (this also work on Mac OS X, though doesn't appear to support formats besides .txt)

Comment: "History Export" addon is no longer available.

Answer (score 4):

1. Sort history using `view->By Site`, or `view->By Date`, or `view->By Site and Date`
2. right click on any site or date
3. click `copy`
4. To get just the URLs, paste in a text editor
5. To get hyperlinks, paste into something that supports hyperlinks (for e.g.) word.

No add-on required.

Comment: Exactly the simple solution I was hoping for, thank you!

Comment: One can also select multiple entries and copy all in 1 go.

Answer (score 2):

2023 None of the ones I tried here worked very well for me. In the end I added all my History to Bookmarks as follows: I searched all History for a / (or : or space, they found the same number), then selected all, right-clicked and chose Add to Bookmarks. It came up with a form which I did not know how to fill in but after a minute changed to a simpler form, requiring only a folder name for the new bookmarks.

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to what's listed here is the add-on "[Enhanced History Manager](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=97504)", which essentially allows you to do what you're talking about.

Comment: Mind adding a link to the extension you mention?

Comment: You won't find this via a Firefox add-on search for its name

Comment: My concern is this software is massively out of date (2005).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using **[FEBE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/febe/)** addon, which provides backups of many itens, including the history as JSON file.

> FEBE (Firefox Environment Backup Extension) allows you to quickly and
>   easily backup your Firefox extensions. In fact, it goes beyond just
>   backing up -- It will actually rebuild your extensions individually
>   into installable .xpi files.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  JakeGould improved your answer while I was commenting.  Just FYI, the site's standards have changed a bit since this question was posted.  The guidelines for software recommendations are described [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers).  Nobody's going to hold you to a higher standard than other answers on this old question.  But on a question without pre-existing "low quality" (by current standards) answers, posting barely more than a link is likely to attract downvotes.

Comment: Thanks for the complementation, i did not have time to read the (meta) subforums.
But the other answers do not satisfy this question today, since they have unavaliables addons and other programs that require more work for a trivial thing.